# Se corta el audio en segundo plano

Tags: android, audio, mediaplayer, procesos-en-segundo-plano

Trabajo desarrollando una aplicación para **Android** de hace un tiempo y actualmente tengo un pequeño problema con la **gestión del audio** cuando la aplicación está en **segundo plano**. Mi aplicación utiliza un **player** (reproductor) de **vídeo** y de **audio** que permite que cuando el usuario salga de la aplicación (sin cerrarla, solo en segundo plano) este pueda seguir escuchando el audio de lo que estuviera reproduciendo en la aplicación. El problema es que, según he leído, desde el nivel de **API 26**; es decir, **Android 8.0 Oreo** (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background?hl=es-419), se gestiona de una mejor manera el consumo de batería y datos.

El caso es que esta **gestión de ahorro de energía de Android** parece ser que **corta procesos en segundo plano**. Pese a esto, una aplicación como Spotify no tiene en cuenta estas restricciones, por ejemplo, porque sigue ejecutándose tanto tiempo como desee el usuario. Mi problema es que al estar unos **5 minutos reproduciendo contenido en segundo plano** (con la pantalla bloqueada) **se corta el audio** y el usuario debe volver a desbloquear su dispositivo para que vuelva a arrancar la reproducción.

Alguien conoce si se debería implementar algún **permiso** o algún **"Background Manager"** para evitar que esto pase?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano!

Comment: Pon tu código de como reproduces el audio

Comment: Como realizas esto " permite que cuando el usuario salga de la aplicación (sin cerrarla, solo en segundo plano)" ?, agrega el código, por favor revisa [ask] y no olvides realizar el [tour] del sitio, saludos

Comment: Para que puedas seguir reproducciendo el audio deberias lanzarlo dentro de un servicio y adjuntar ese servicio a una notificacion que indique que tu app esta ejecutando, tal como lo hace spotify u otras applicaciones que reproduccen audio en segundo plano. La idea es que el servicio seguira ejecutando mientras la notificacion permanezca activa, cuando el usuario la cancele el servicio se dejara de ejecutar. Este cambio se realizo por cuestiones de seguridad, antes podrias tener ejecutando cosas en segundo plano sin que el usuario se entere.

Comment: @abrahamhs gracias por tu colaboración. La forma en la que desarrollé la reproducción en segundo plano es la siguiente:

`protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "Player Activity Stopped");
        if (!player.isPlaying()){
            player.pause();
        }else{
            player.play();
        }
    }

    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        Log.d(TAG, "Player Activity Restarted");
        if (!player.isPlaying()){
            player.pause();
        }else{
            player.play();
        }
    }`

Comment: Muchas gracias @ErickSilva. He probado ya con crear un proceso en segundo plano pero tampoco se salta las restricciones de Android y el SO lo corta. No sé si existe algún tipo de notificación que ya indique al SO que es un proceso multimedia en segundo plano y que no debe cortar el audio. Yo creo una notificación utilizando la clase NotificationCompat de Android y le meto un MediaStyle.

`androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                        .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())`

Comment: @ErickSilva he estado leyendo sobre el tema y tengo una sample app con Media Player en la que funciona. Como tu dices, crea un servicio donde está el MediaPlayer y luego un MainActivity que le pasa un audio (Intent) a este servicio. En mi caso tengo una clase con el player de Brightcove que extiende de BrightcovePlayer, por lo que si o si debo hacer el servicio aparte y llamar a la clase del BrightcovePlayer para que lo inicialice desde el servicio, verdad? (Aparte de implementar en el servicio la notificación y la gestión del audio en segundo plano).

Comment: @JorgeHuertaCasanova por lo que leo, venis bien encaminado. Crea el player desde el servicio, el servicio se conecta a la notificacion y todo eso queda corriendo en segundo plano, no tengo un ejemplo a mano como poder responder apropiadamente a la pregunta. Si lo logras subelo un ejemplo pequeño. El manejo de servicios en segundo plano, suele ser algo problematico.

Comment: @ErickSilva gracias por contestar. Adjunto un código que funciona también. Es una sample app de Google en la que utiliza el ExoPlayer. El player que yo utilizo (Brightcove) utiliza como core el ExoPlayer de Google también, por lo que es más fácil adaptarlo a mi proyecto. Adjunto el código en el siguiente enlace.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hpaHKCrlawQck01DdDFtpf-NvJgybvtd

Un saludo!